# Derivative of Entropy with Respect to Energy and Displacements

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, entropy

I am trying hard to understand the solution to a problem from David Chandler's Introduction to Modern Statistical Mechanics. The equation of state for a rubber band is given in terms of S(E,L,n) where E is the internal energy, L is the length of the rubber band, and n (I believe) is the number of molecules making up the rubber band. The task is to find an expression for the tension, $f$, as a function of L/n and the temperature T.

Earlier in the chapter (pg. 10), it is shown that for generalized displacements X and generalized forces f $$ \frac{\partial S}{\partial \textbf{X}}|_E = -\frac{\textbf{f}}{T} $$

Additionally, earlier in the chapter (pg. 9). It is explained that $ \frac{\partial S}{\partial \textbf{X}}|_E \textrm{ }d\textbf{X} =  \frac{\partial S}{\partial X_1}|_E \textrm{ }dX_1 + \frac{\partial S}{\partial X_2}|_E \textrm{ }dX_2 ...  $

Therefore, when I tried to solve this problem, taking that general equation above and applying it to this system I arrived at:

$$ \frac{\partial S}{\partial \textbf{X}}|_E = \frac{\partial S}{\partial L}|_{E,n} + \frac{\partial S}{\partial n}|_{E,L} = -\frac{f}{T}  $$

However, in the solutions manual, it is stated that:

$$ \frac{\partial S}{\partial L}|_{E,n}  = -\frac{f}{T} $$

**Why is the $ \frac{\partial S}{\partial n}|_{E,L} $  not included?** At first I was thinking that the variables for $n$ and $L$ get some fundamentally different treatment, but in fact on page 6 he explicitly states that: " We choose to ignore the distinction [between the composition variables (n) and mechanical variables] because one can ...design experiments in which transfer of moles occurs with the consumption... of work".

Here is the specific form of the equation of state if it is relevant:

$$ S = nl_0\gamma  \sqrt{\frac{\theta E}{nl_0}} - nl_0\gamma[\frac{1}{2}(\frac{L}{nl_o})^2 + \frac{nl_o}{L} - \frac{3}{2}]$$

Another [post here many years ago](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81218/equation-of-state-of-a-rubber-band) asked about the same question (problem 1.2 from David Chandler's Intro. to Modern Stat. Mech.) , but the answer to that post does not answer my specific question about the problem.

Comment: Does n change when you stretch it.  What happened to the factor $\partial n/\partial L$ in your equation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not statistical mechanics, but standard thermo-statics. Starting from the Gibbs equation for the internal energy with variables $S, X_1, X_2, ..$ you have
$$dE=TdS+\sum_k Y_k dX_k \tag{1}$$ or expressed for $S$ is
$$dS=\frac{1}{T}dE - \sum_k \frac{Y_k}{T}dX_k \tag{2}.$$
Here $E$ and the other extensives $X_k$ are the *independent* variables therefore you have $$\frac{\partial S}{\partial E} = \frac{1}{T} \tag{3}$$and
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial X_k} = -\frac{Y_k}{T} \tag{4}.$$
Eq. (4) is the formula you have been asking about when $X_1=L$, the length, and $Y_1 = f$ the corresponding conjugate intensive, i.e., the tension, $\frac{\partial S}{\partial L} = -\frac{f}{T}$. The number of molecules $n$ does not show up *there*. When it is included in the energy (or entropy) form, $dU=TdS+fdL+\mu n$, then it shows up with *its* conjugate intensive, the so-called chemical potential, usually denoted by $\mu$, therefore $\frac{\partial S}{\partial n} = -\frac{\mu}{T}$.

Comment: To clarify for others, the paragraph at the end of @hyportnex's answer clarified things for me by thinking of it like this: $$dS = \frac{1}{T}dE - \frac{f}{T}dL - \frac{\mu}{T}dn$$. Then the question is how to isolate the tension, f from this equation? f is isolated by looking for $\frac{\partial S}{\partial L}|_{E,n}$ which gives the equation in the solutions manual.